# Stanford iphone dev calculator example crashes on selecting operation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm completely new to objective-c, so I have no idea why this is happening. I'm still trying to wrap my brain around the concepts and I don't know what I'm looking for, so I hope one of you nice, smart people could assist me. I'm sure it's something stupid that I don't realize is a problem.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *display;
    CalculatorBrain *brain;
    BOOL userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m:
(with the crash occuring on "NSString *operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];" near the end)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (CalculatorBrain *)brain
{
    if (brain) {
        brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
    }
    return brain;
}

- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSString *digit = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
        [display setText:[[display text] stringByAppendingString:digit]];
    } else {
        [display setText:digit];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {
        [[self brain] setOperand:[[display text] doubleValue]];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
    }
    NSString *operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    double result = [[self brain] performOperation:operation];
    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", result]];
}

@end
```

CalculatorBrain.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject {
    double operand;
    NSString *waitingOperation;
    double waitingOperand;
}

- (void)setOperand:(double)anOperand;
- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation;

@end
```

CalculatorBrain.m:

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"

@implementation CalculatorBrain

- (void)setOperand:(double)anOperand
{
    operand = anOperand;
}

- (void)performWaitingOperation
{
    if ([@"+" isEqual:waitingOperation]) {
        operand = waitingOperand + operand;
    } else if ([@"-" isEqual:waitingOperation]) {
        operand = waitingOperand - operand;
    } else if ([@"*" isEqual:waitingOperation]) {
        operand = waitingOperand * operand;
    } else if ([@"/" isEqual:waitingOperation]) {
        if (operand) {
        operand = waitingOperand / operand;
        }
    }
}

- (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
    if ([operation isEqual:@"sqrt"]) {
        operand = sqrt(operand);
    } else {
        [self performWaitingOperation];
        waitingOperation = operation;
        waitingOperand = operand;
    }
    return operand;
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance for any help or tips... I have no idea what I'm doing :)

Comment: did you get some message about an object not responding to the `titleLabel` selector?  can you tell us any more about the crash?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CalculatorBrain *)brain {
 if (brain) {
     brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
 }     
 return brain; 
 }
```

Though there may be other things wrong with the code, this one immediately stuck out. You're missing the ! operator.

```
- (CalculatorBrain *)brain {
 if (!brain) {
     brain = [[CalculatorBrain alloc] init];
 }     
 return brain; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out the reason of the crash in the debug console of XCode.

As a side note, why dont you use `[sender currentTitle]` instead of `[[titleLabel] text]`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was having the exact same problem as this asker and I found I had accidentally added a breakpoint on this same line. Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.